# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'builddef.lst' (googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:)

Tags: android, gradle, mp4

I got this error while using **googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:** for trimming video I used this but when I used **telegram video compressor**
library it starts show this thing|..

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'builddef.lst'
```

I searched some of the question in stack, and other sites but It didn't solved my problem ......I wasted 3 days solve this problem please does anyone knows how can I solve this..I used telegram video compression libs which has **isoparser**  [please see this image in telegram libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEmTB.png)
if I remove the **googlecode.mp4parser.isoparser** library from my app the error goes. but I can't remove this I am using this for video trimmer ...what can do please help me

**here...what I tried**

I used this code but it shows compilation failed and a new error occur

```
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'builddef.lst'
    exclude 'version.txt'
    exclude 'isoparser-default.properties'
}
```

this I is the error when I add this code to android{}

```
 Program type already present: com.coremedia.iso.BoxParser
 Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.coremedia.iso.BoxParser, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

this

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/project.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/builddef.lst'
    }
```

Comment: I think you have uploaded duplicate files in your packaging. please check

Comment: I am using iso parser from telegram source code .....for video compressing when I implement  **k4lvideotrimmer**  from GitHub it shows this error

Comment: @newlearner did you find any solution regarding this? I am also looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gradle file for app. There might be some library which you would have referred twice.
If you can share the gradle contents here, I can help you identify them.
Also try cleaning the project and build it again.

Comment: no I don't have....but sillicompressor and k4l trimmer uses different isoparser ..that is problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside the android {...} closure in the build.gradle for your app module to resolve issue:

```
android {
    ...
      compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    ...
    }
```