# How can I add data and get data from model class in android?

Tags: android

I have a model class called **PhotoviewHolder** I want to add data  and get data from the model class;

```
class PhotoViewModel implement ListViewModel {
String imagePath;
String date_created;
String description;

public PhotoViewModel(String imagePath, String date_created, String description) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.date_created = date_created;
    this.description = description;
}


public PhotoViewModel() {

}
public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}

public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public String getDate_created() {
    return date_created;
}

public void setDate_created(String date_created) {
    this.date_created = date_created;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PhotoViewModel{" +
            "imagePath='" + imagePath + '\'' +
            ", date_created='" + date_created + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            '}';
} 
}
```

**Here What I have tried ::**

> For ex: I added this code mainactivity>> I am only getting the image
>   path in  mainactivity where this code is not getting the data in
>   another activity...

```
       List<Photo> photos = mPhotos;
                List<ListViewModel> listViewModels = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Photo photo : photos) {
                    if(photo.getPopularlist().contains("true")){
                        if(photo.getType_post().equals("Photo")){
                            List<PhotoViewModel> pho = new ArrayList<>();
                            PhotoViewModel p = new PhotoViewModel();
                            p.setImagePath(photo.getImage_path());
                            pho.add(p);

                            listViewModels.add(new PhotoViewModel(photo.getImage_path(),photo.getDescription(),photo.getDate_created()));
                           // Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: alphs"+photoViewModel1.getImagePath());

                        }
                        if(photo.getType_post().equals("Video")){
                            listViewModels.add(new VideoViewModel(photo.getImage_path()));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

this code were I get the data but it does not getting data it shows **null** can anyone please help me ...I am new to this

```
PhotoViewModel photoViewModel= new PhotoViewModel();
Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: photoviewmodeldata"+photoViewModel.getImagePath());
```

// this my adapter code

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup
```

parent, int viewType) {

```
    //findViewById...
    mContext = parent.getContext();
    switch (viewType) {
        case ListViewModel.VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO:
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_list, parent, false);
            mContext = parent.getContext();
            return new PhotoHolder(v);


        case ListViewModel.VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO:
            View i = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_type, parent, false);
            mContext = parent.getContext();
            return new VideoHolder(i);


    }
    return null;

}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mListViewModels.get(position).getViewType();
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case ListViewModel.VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO:
            final PhotoHolder photoview = (PhotoHolder) holder;
            mPhotoHolder = photoview;
            mPhoto = new Photo();
            PhotoViewModel p =  new PhotoViewModel();
            photoview.usersPhoto = new StringBuilder();
            final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
           PhotoViewModel photoViewModel= new PhotoViewModel();
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: photoviewmodeldata "+photoViewModel.getImagePath());
            break;

        case ListViewModel.VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO:
            final VideoHolder viewHolder2 = (VideoHolder) holder;
            mVideoHolder = viewHolder2;
            viewHolder2.usersVideo = new StringBuilder()
        //get the profile image and username

            break;
    }
}
public ListViewModel getItem(int position) {
    return mListViewModels.get(position);
}
public void setListViewModels(List<ListViewModel> listViewModels) {
    mListViewModels = listViewModels;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
     return mListViewModels == null? 0 : mListViewModels.size();
}
public Trending_adapter(){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is self explainable for the issue you are facing.

```
PhotoViewModel photoViewModel= new PhotoViewModel();
Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: photoviewmodeldata"+photoViewModel.getImagePath());
```

You care creating new object and trying to get data from the new object without initializing data to that object.

Also, I don't see proper need of these lines, in your code.

```
List<PhotoViewModel> pho = new ArrayList<>();
PhotoViewModel p = new PhotoViewModel();
p.setImagePath(photo.getImage_path());
pho.add(p);
```

Please clear all this confusion and make it proper with OOPs concepts.

> UPDATE:

Okay. As your adapter code, you are using below code to get data of ListItem from Array. Instead of getting value from `ArrayList` you are creating new instance of `PhotoViewModel`.

```
case ListViewModel.VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO:
        final PhotoHolder photoview = (PhotoHolder) holder;
        mPhotoHolder = photoview;
        mPhoto = new Photo();
        PhotoViewModel p =  new PhotoViewModel();
        photoview.usersPhoto = new StringBuilder();
        final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
       PhotoViewModel photoViewModel= new PhotoViewModel();
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: photoviewmodeldata "+photoViewModel.getImagePath());
        break;
```

Try fetching item using `getItem(position)` method. You will get object of relative position from array.

```
        final PhotoHolder photoview = (PhotoHolder) holder;

        ListViewModel listItem = getItem(position); // getting item from listview. Please check of positioning by yourself.

        /** Omiting extra code */ 

        if(listItem instance of PhotoViewModel){ //because PhotoViewModel extends ListViewModel 
        //and you used parent class in ArrayList instead of Two Different Child Class. 
            PhotoViewModel photoViewModel =  (PhotoViewModel)listItem; // downcasting to child class
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: photoviewmodeldata "+photoViewModel.getImagePath());
        }
        break;
```

Comment: @newlearner are you using RecyclerView? First, Post your adapter code, so we can understand the proper logic behind your code.

Comment: okk please wait...was posted adapter but some one edited this question

Comment: @newlearner please check update answer. I have just put required code for the answer need, you can add extra code as your requirement.

Comment: bro...I have another question can you please help me

Comment: I am facing this problem please help me ......[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359779/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-builddef-lst-googlecode ]i have posted this  question  on stack overflow but no able to answer...please can you help me